Align text to left and image to right side of the page
Can somebody please help me how to make the image show up on the right side?
I can't figure out why it's not doing anything.


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.carousel .list .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
}

.carousel .list .item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.carousel .list .item .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 1140px;
  max-width: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding-right: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 10px #0004;
}

.carousel .list .item .title,
.carousel .list .item .topic {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

.carousel .list .item .topic {
  color: #f1683a;
}
<!-- carousel -->
<div class="carousel">
  <!-- list item -->
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placehold.co/800x800" />
      <div class="content">
        <div class="img_right">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" />
        </div>
        <div class="title">text-text</div>
        <br class="des" />
        <!-- lorem 50 -->
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Neolix/72gjnduw/2/

do you want the text to flow around the image or just be splittet?

splitter, I want to have the text in its kind of like separate box and the image to be in its own separate box on right (also for the image I will want to give it radius so the corners are rounder and give it a backdrop shadow or something so it looks better and it's not that edgy)

maybe you should rethink the layouts with grid or flex for img+text and use figure+figcaption. as HTML structure. It will be simplier to handle. flex & grid allows to reorder elements very easily : https://jsfiddle.net/vjwmce56/

Wrap the image and text content inside a container.
Use display: flex to align the image and text side by side.


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.carousel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.img_right img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.content {
  max-width: 60%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 10px #0004;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

.topic {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  color: #f1683a;
}
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="title">text-text</div>
          <div class="des">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
            sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
            et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="img_right">
          <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" alt="Placeholder Image" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




If you do not want to adjust the HTML then you can use CSS-Grid. You can place the image inside the 2nd column by using grid-column: 2;. To not space the content unintended, you should let the image take 3 rows height: grid-template-rows: span 3;
I replace your title with a <h2> tag as for titles you should always use headlines not an unsemantic div.


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  .img_right {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: span 3;
  }
}
<div class="content">
  <div class="img_right">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" />
  </div>
  <h2 class="title">text-text</h2>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>




I tried it with display: flex. And to move the image to the right I used flex-direction: row-reverse which moves the image from left to right.
In addition, I gave the text an extra container. It makes it easier and better to work with Flexbox.


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.carousel .list .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 0;
}

.carousel .list .item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/*Just for testing, can be ignored*/

.img_right {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 240px;
}

.carousel .list .item .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  width: 1140px;
  max-width: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  padding-right: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 10px #0004;
  /*EDIT*/
  display: flex;
  /* Keeps it aligned */
  align-items: center;
  /* MOVES THE IMAGE TO RIGHT */
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.carousel .list .item .title,
.carousel .list .item .topic {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

.carousel .list .item .topic {
  color: #f1683a;
}
<!-- carousel -->
<div class="carousel">
  <!-- list item -->
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="./Assets/infoBackground.png" />
      <div class="content">
        <div class="img_right">
          <img src="./Assets/infoCover.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <!--extra class for text container to keep the text in one box.-->
        <div class="content-text">
          <div class="title">text-text</div>
          <br class="des" />
          <!-- lorem 50 -->
          text-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-text text-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-text text-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-text text-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-text
          text-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-texttext-text
          <br />

          <br />text-texttext-texttext-text<br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




That's exactly what I initially did too. I just used a grid as it is then possible to do without altering the HTML code. If altering the HTML is acceptable this would be still the way to go for me.

Yeah its just a prefered method from me. I do not work often with grid :D

That worked, but how can I make it more to the right and a bit bigger pls? Like on this screenshot the content box is empty on the right side and I want the picture to be in that right side of the content box. - https://postimg.cc/ZC3B7Gvk

You can do it either with justify-content: space-between  or justify-content: space-around. gap would  be a solution to. Otherwise you can use align-self: end too. I've linked a helpfull page to learn Flexbox. If you want to learn it with more fun Flexbox Froggy is the best page.
To make it bigger you jsut need to increase the width and the height of the content or container.

Nice I like the foggy thing, makes enjoyable to learn :)
But in my code I don't think it's doing anything I tried all the options you suggested but the picture didn't move :(. I was adding the code into .carousel .list .item .content {}

https://jsfiddle.net/sgzvyrq7/41/ This is my go on this. I tried to keep it simple. Resize the window and you will see the "magic" of justify-content: space-between. Maybe you have to rework your code a little bit.

Hmm, don't know about that , when I add the picture to it it goes out of the wrapper and prolongs the page as well.

also not sure why is it doing this on the preview screen also when I open it on live server and I open "inspect elements" it's cut like this -_-
this is how it looks on tablet view - https://postimg.cc/SY2K2vzf

Can you put an updated code snippet of your code in your question? Just add an aditional snippet to it. So we have an older Version and an updated one.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I had to make a bit of changes.
Firstly, you should have a separate container (DIV) for the text elements and for the image elements.
Then you can create a div that wraps both those containers and use flexbox to align them in row and reversed.
Then you set the carousel and text to be specific widths in relation to the parent.
The text-text should be wrapped around a tag (heading or paragraph depending on your goal for it). The lorem-50 should also be wraped around a paragraph tag.
I was not sure what you wanted to do with the first image but i assumed since it is a carousel both the images should be stacked. I sourced the same image for it just with a different color so you can visualize it better.
You can delete the border property, it's there just so you see the containers better.
You have a better explanation for each step in the code itself.


@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.carousel .list .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative; /*you want the image to move freely not its container*/
}

#img1 { /*I am not sure what you want to do with this image but since it is a carousel I believe you want the images to be stacked*/
  width: 600px; /*match the other image's size*/
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: none; /*we don't need the object-fit property so I set it to none*/
  z-index: 10; /* higher index so it stays on top of all the other elements;*/
  position: absolute; /*so it moves freely*/
  margin-right: 0; /*send it to the right*/
}

#img2 { /* target the img itself */
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #0004; /*box shadow instead of text because you want to target the image*/
  position: relative; /*this should move in relation to its container*/
}

p {
  color: #f1683a;
}

/*set the main-container to display items in a row and reverse them*/
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between; /*this will space the items so that the first touchs the left margin and the second touches the right margin*/
  align-items: center; /*this will align the items vertically*/
  width: 100%; /* sets the width base to work with*/
}

.text {
  width: 40%; /*sets the width of the text container in relation to its parent (main-container)*/
  padding: 2px; /*children will space between each other and the container borders*/
  text-align: center; /*text will align center*/
}

.carousel {
  width: 60%; /*sets the width of the carousel container in relation of its parent (main-container)*/
}

.border1 {
  border: solid 1px red; /*just so you see the containers*/
}

.border2 {
   border: solid 1px yellow; /*just so you see the containers*/
}
<!--Create a main container that wraps all elements around-->
<div class='main-container border1'>
  
  <!--Make the carousel the container for all the image-related divs-->
    <div class='carousel border2'>
      <div class='list'>
        <!--Wrap the images in one div-->
        <div class="item">
          <img id='img1' src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/600x400.png"/>
          <img id='img2' src="https://placehold.co/600x400" />
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--wrap all the text elements with its own Div-->
    <div class='text border2'>
      
      <!--Wrap title with a heading tag-->
      <h1>Text-Text</h1>
      
   <!--Wrap text with a paragraph tag-->
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      
    </div>
</div>



I removed this part of your css:
.carousel .list .item .title,
.carousel .list .item .topic {
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

Because in my opinion, it is too big for the text but you can still do it, just target the selectors h1 and p instead.
I also merged the content div with the item div so the content div does not exist anymore.
Here are some links that may help you in the future:
Flexbox Guide by CSS-tricks
Flexbox Guide by W3Schools
Stacking Elements in CSS - guide
Hope this helped :);

Thanks, I'll try see how it goes. The first image which is ./Assets/infoBackground.png is just a background on the page nothing else with it. and the 2nd picture is the important one to have on the right side of the text - https://postimg.cc/ZC3B7Gvk

@Neolix If it is a page background, remove that image from the item div and from the whole html code. Also remove the css styling for it. If you want to set a background image to the whole page, just do it on the css file for the body selector like this: body {background-image: url('./Assets/infoBackground.png');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;}

@Neolix You can also play with it a bit. You can read more about the background-image property on this guide: W3Schools Guide for backgroud-image Hope this helps :)

yep that helped thanks, now I just need to mess around with the text and the 2nd image to be centered on the screen and the text to be on the right side and the image on the left

@Neolix Glad I could help! If you want the text and image to be centered on the screen change the justify-content to center on the main-container (on css). And to put the text on right side and image on left just change the flex-direction to row (instead of row-reverse).
